# Why one byte & 2 byte padding in front of MAC PDU & Why not in end of MAC PDU Header

Tags: lte

Why one byte and two byte padding header is added in front of MAC PDU and more than 2 byte padding header is added in last of of MAC sub header. Instead of that they can keep padding in last sub header, what is the reason behind that.

Answer (score 0):

In case of single byte or two byte padding , If you add sub header in last then you need to mention length field in the before sub header , but you have only one or two byte extra then if you add length field in the last one byte will be extra needed. that is the reason padding is done in the end.

Say example MAC is having 101 byte of grant and RLC data is one PDU which is of 99 byte and MAC header is needed 1 byte because only one PDU so one byte is enough. follow below first image,padding is needed for 1 more byte (99(Data) + 1 (SDU header)+ 1 (padding)). If i add padding in the end then (see second image) it will become 101 byte but if i add in the beginning(see image 3) it will be sufficient. For Padding sub header no need to mention length even if it is not a last sub header ,implicitly receiver MAC knows it.

So this is the reason one or two byte padding is done in the beginning.

[Pictorial view click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ4N7.jpg)